# xml conversion to csv outputs nothing

Tags: python, xml, csv, neural-network

I have a dataset of currency where each photo has a corresponding xml file that describes it. I need to convert xml files to csv files in order to use them in cnn to build a model for recognizing currency. The code has a function that displays the number of xml files and classes that have been generated but it gives me zero!

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers
from keras import datasets
from keras import models
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from os import listdir, mkdir
from os.path import isdir, join, isfile, splitext
import re
from tqdm import tqdm
import os

os.environ['TFF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'


class Processing():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ANN_FILE = None
        self.CLASSES = set()
        self.CLASSES_file = None
        self.COUNT_XML = set()
        self.COUNT_IMAGES = set()
        self.COUNT_BOXES = 0

    def xml_files_in_folder(self, folder):
        return [join(folder, f) for f in listdir(folder) if re.match(r'.*\.(xml|XML)', f, flags=re.I)]

    def init_file_csv(self, _path):
        self.ANN_FILE = open(_path, 'w')

    def write_file_csv(self, row):
        _path, x, y, x2, y2, label = row
        insert_row = f'{_path},{x},{y},{x2},{y2},{label}'
        self.ANN_FILE.write(insert_row)
        self.ANN_FILE.write('\n')

    def read_xml_file(self, _file):
        self.COUNT_XML.add(_file)
        tree = ET.parse(_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for boxes in root.iter('object'):
            filename = root.find('filename').text
            full_path = _file.replace(splitext(_file)[1], splitext(filename)[1])
            label = boxes.find('name').text
            ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = None, None, None, None

            ymin = int(boxes.find("bndbox/ymin").text)
            xmin = int(boxes.find("bndbox/xmin").text)
            ymax = int(boxes.find("bndbox/ymax").text)
            xmax = int(boxes.find("bndbox/xmax").text)

            one_line = [full_path, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, label]
            self.write_file_csv(one_line)
            self.CLASSES.add(label)

            self.COUNT_IMAGES.add(filename)
            self.COUNT_BOXES += 1

    def write_classes_csv(self):
        with open(self.CLASSES_file, 'w') as classes_file:
            for id, cl in enumerate(self.CLASSES):
                classes_file.write('{},{}'.format(cl, id))
                classes_file.write('\n')
        classes_file.close()

    def Done(self):
        self.ANN_FILE.close()


class Big_Engine():
    def __init__(self):
        self.PATH_DATA = None
        self.Processing = Processing()

    def SETUP(self, data: str, ann_file: str, classes_file: str):
        self.PATH_DATA = data
        self.Processing.CLASSES_file = classes_file
        self.Processing.init_file_csv(ann_file)

    def RUN(self):
        for sub_dir in tqdm(listdir(self.PATH_DATA)):
            end_dir = join(self.PATH_DATA, sub_dir)
            if not isdir(end_dir):
                continue
            for xml_path in self.Processing.xml_files_in_folder(end_dir):
                self.Processing.read_xml_file(xml_path)

    def PrintData(self):
        print(f"[Count Xml files]  | {len(self.Processing.COUNT_XML)}")
        print(f"[Count Images]  | {len(self.Processing.COUNT_IMAGES)}")
        print(f"[Count Classes]  | {len(self.Processing.CLASSES)}")
        print(f"[Count BOXES]  | {self.Processing.COUNT_BOXES}")

    def SetEnd(self):
        self.Processing.write_classes_csv()
        self.Processing.Done()
        self.PrintData()
        print("[bye] - Done..")


LetsGo = Big_Engine()
LetsGo.SETUP(data='E:\dataset1', ann_file='E:\d_annotation_custom.csv', classes_file='E:\classes_n.csv')
LetsGo.RUN()
LetsGo.SetEnd()
```

and this is the output :

```
100%|██████████| 2000/2000 [00:00<00:00, 32010.01it/s]
[Count Xml files]  | 0
[Count Images]  | 0
[Count Classes]  | 0
[Count BOXES]  | 0
[bye] - Done..
```

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text. Post the text.

Comment: @Tomalak Okay, I edited it as you said

Answer (score 2):

I think the main issue is that you are over-engineering. This makes the code hard to follow, more difficult to test, error-prone.

Classes are great, but you really don't need two classes with a ton of methods for what's basically a straight file processing loop. Keep it simple, it will be much easier to read and debug.

Two functions are plenty.

- One that takes an XML file, and generates tuples with data
- One that takes directory- and CSV names, and runs the file processing loop

Like this:

```
import csv
from os import path
from glob import glob 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def read_xml(xml_file):
    ''' outputs (img_path, name, ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax) from xml_file ''' 
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    filename = root.find('filename').text
    for obj in root.iter('object'):
        yield (
            path.splitext(xml_file)[0] + path.splitext(filename)[1],
            obj.find('name').text,
            int(obj.find('bndbox/ymin').text),
            int(obj.find('bndbox/xmin').text),
            int(obj.find('bndbox/ymax').text),
            int(obj.find('bndbox/xmax').text),
        )

def process(data_files_path, ann_file, classes_file):
    ''' processes all XML files under data_dir, writes CSV files, returns the entities '''
    result = {'classes': set(), 'xml_files': set(), 'images': set(), 'count_boxes': 0}

    with open(ann_file, 'w', newline='') as ann_fp:
        ann_writer = csv.writer(ann_fp)
        for xml_file in glob(data_files_path):
            result['xml_files'].add(xml_file)
            for img_path, x, y, x2, y2, label in read_xml(xml_file):
                ann_writer.writerow([img_path, x ,y, x2, y2, label])
                result['classes'].add(label)
                result['images'].add(img_path)
                result['count_boxes'] += 1

    with open(classes_file, 'w', newline='') as classes_fp:
        classes_writer = csv.writer(classes_fp)
        for id, cl in enumerate(result['classes']):
            classes_writer.writerow([cl, id])
    
    return result

result = process(r'E:\dataset1\*\*.xml', r'E:\d_annotation_custom.csv', r'E:\classes_n.csv')

print(f"[Count Xml files]  | {len(result['xml_files'])}")
print(f"[Count Images]  | {len(result['images'])}")
print(f"[Count Classes]  | {len(result['classes'])}")
print(f"[Count BOXES]  | {result['count_boxes']}")
print("[bye] - Done.")
```

Output with a make-shift test XML

```
[Count Xml files]  | 1
[Count Images]  | 1
[Count Classes]  | 1
[Count BOXES]  | 1
[bye] - Done.
```